# Request only the number of computers in DS SDK

Tags: deepsecurity

Deepsecurity api takes a long time to parse all pcs, so i need need to parse only the quantity of computers via SDK to make a time estimate, and a progress bar for the user.

is this possible? i didn't find any methods in the docs for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the new /api (and associated SDKs) don't have a way to just count the number of computers. That may be something offered in the future, or Computers API performance may improve to make it less necessary.

Meanwhile, the SOAP API does have hostStatusSummaryRetrieve() method, which should give you counts.

A bit more info on the SOAP API vs. /api, and some links to other SOAP docs, here: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_3/transition-from-the-soap-api

P.S. I work for Trend Micro on Deep Security.